# Parsing a large value that includes 3 smaller values of scientifc notation

Tags: vb.net

I'm using VB.Net 2013 and really could use some help.  Perhaps I have been staring at it too long.  I am presented with a value from a variable.  The specific value is this

- 3.190E+01+3.366E+01+8.036E+00

The value is actually 3 smaller values in scientific notation as follows

- 3.190E+01
- 3.366E+01
- 8.036E+00

I need to get the individual values into individual variables.  Once I have the individual values I need to calculate the notation of each value so 3.190E+01 is equivalent to 3.190*10^1 and 8.036E+00 is equivalent to 8.036*10^0.  I can probably figure out the last part of this question if I can just get the individual values. The caveat is that the numbers will vary in size and the scientific notation part will not always be the same.  I do believe it will always be E+XX though so possible to use some regex stuff that I don't fully understand.

Thank you, I look forward to your help and it is very much appreciated.

Comment: This notation is supported by `Double.Parse`. For example: `Dim doubleVal As Double = Double.Parse("3.190E+01")` stores the right value (31.9). But even though you are asking about an extremely simple string parsing situation. You can use `Split` and for "d"/"e" as separator (then forming the number from the parts with basic operations or even via string concatenation). You should do some effort by your own before asking here.

Comment: Regex is exceptionally well documented - the internet is full of help and guidance.  Suggest you take some time to learn, it's really not that hard.  An excellent tool is regex101 - you can build and test regexps there live.  For example : https://regex101.com/r/nR9vK1/1

Comment: Simplicity is relative.  I do appreciate your guidance and pointing me to the right direction.  Thank you.